# Integration off-centered cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I have a problem, I need to integrate a function over a cylindrical region.

$$\int_{-z}^{z}\int_{0}^{2\pi }\int_{0}^{r}f(r,\theta,z)rdrd\theta dz$$

For this used a cylindrical coordinate system. However, this cylinder can be moved to any location i.e. it is not always at the centre of the coordinate system. For example, what if the centre of the cylinder is at:
$$r=2,z=0$$
Can anyone help me in determining the integration limits for such a case?

Comment: Why not move the center of your cylindrical coordinate system to the center of the cylinder?

Comment: For your third integral, you are integrating over $z$ with bounds depending on $z$. Maybe consider using a different dummy variable

Comment: @Arthur because I need to move the cylinder (detector) inside the field to determine the average value of the field at different locations. For this, I need to integrate the given function over the volume of the detector at different locations.